# How to build a view controller container with infinite child controllers?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I want to build a app like this one named "next day" ([here's some snapshots](http://zuimeia.com/app/102/?category=24)).
With swiping right, it goes to previous view controller witch shows one picture and the date. If i keep swiping, it'll switch view controller on and on. Please tell me what does the architecture look like and how to do that. Sorry for my broken English and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageViewController` is exactly for this. You can either instantiate it directly or subclass it, but in both cases you need to provide a data source which conforms to `<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>` to dynamically provide a view controller for each page after setting an initial *default* page for the current day. You will need a way to keep track of your current page, which can be a property on your custom view controller subclass which you’ll be returning for each page.

Comment: Ah, yes, the use case sounded familiar to me :) +1, this is the way to go.